# Blender game upload to app store?

Tags: game-engine

I have started with a game project and wanted to ask whether the game can also be designed for an App store, app.

And change the control on touch screen?

Comment: Blender games run exclusively in Windows Mac and Linux. Uploading to appstores is probably an exclusive and highly supervised procedure that has nothing to do with Blender itself, and as such is considered off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Blender games are, even if you have made them an .exe file, running in Blender. The .exe file just gives you a shortcut to the game in the .Blend file. You won't be able to change this. .exe files only run on Windows PC's and there's going to be a whole lot to it. I suggest you learn how to write C# and JS script and completely remake the game in Unity3D. You can import all objects from your current scene, materials too, but you'll have to program everything over again. The code your game is made of (Python) is specific Python script for Blender and won't work on other platforms.

I suggest you go and do some research on how Blender works, and how android works.